# Parse.com saveInBackground not working on all devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, device, background-task

I have a simple piece of code:

```
ParseObject testobject = new ParseObject("Test");
testobject.put("customerName", "John");
testobject.saveInBackground();
```

If I run this on my emulator, it works, a Test class is made in my Parse project and the value John is added to the Row customername.

If I run this on my mobile phone the result is also succesful.

But if I run the exact same program on my Tablet, nothing happens.

(the callback = null, .getResult() and .getError() are also null)

Any idea where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Wi-fi on your phone or using mobile internet? Depending on where you are (Home, School/University) they may have blocked some ports which stop the service from running.

Something I saw is, you've got spaces between 'testobject .put' and 'testobject .saveInBackground();', that may be your issue?

Comment: Oh no the spaces are not the issue (thats just bad copy pasting into this stackoverflow).
I am using Wi-fi on my phone, and my tablet.
The emulator runs on my computer which uses a direct internet connection (lan)
I also checked testobject.deleteInBackground(); which works on emulator, mobile AND tablet.

Comment: add this into your code:  testobject.put("Cheatmode", false);

Comment: i just tried this:   ParseObject testobject = new ParseObject("Test");
  testobject.put("customerName", "John");
  testobject.put("Cheatmode", true);
  testobject.saveInBackground(); which didnt get saved using my tablet, also   ParseObject testobject = new ParseObject("Test");
  testobject.put("Cheatmode", true);
  testobject.saveInBackground();
 didnt get saved using my tablet.

Comment: could it be an issue with the minSdkVersion or the targetSdkVersion that i defined in the android manifest ? My manifest declares this now :     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: sorry my mistake, try testobject.put("Cheatmode", false);

Comment: Change your minSdk to 4 and your targetSdk to 15? See if that works for you?

Comment: Changed the Sdk settings as you suggested. Nothing changed.